# Can't handle Button Click in Popup

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro

I use [CaliburnMicro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) in my Windows Store App.
 All works great, but when I put Button in Popup, method in ViewModel doesn't called. If I move Button from Popup to Page - all works like a charm.

Ex. code
.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="Method1"/>
<Popup  Width="400" Height="300" IsOpen="True">
    <Button x:Name="Method2"/>
</Popup>
```

in ViewModel.cs

```
public void Method1() //this method is called
    {
      var a = 10; 
    }

public void Method2() //this method isn't called
    {
      var a = 10; 
    }
```

Need some help.

**UPDATE**

I also tried to add to my popup

```
 cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"
```

And in code I check `popup.Datacontext` is the nested ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly declare an action message by doing something like this.

```
<Popup  Width="400" Height="300" IsOpen="True">
     <Button x:Name="Method2" Content="Popup}"
             cal:Message.Attach="Method2"/>
</Popup>
```

More detail about Action [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: I wil try it on monday, and responce you.